# Is possible to get coordinates from click on flutter map - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I'm using flutter map in my application, is possible when I click on some place on map to get coordinates from that place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onTap Handler

```
 GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0, 0)),
            onTap: (position) {},
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to get coordinates from a click on a Flutter map. You can use the onTap() callback to get the coordinates of the place that was tapped.